# $display floating-point number in console

Tags: floating-point, verilog, ieee-754

I'm trying to display an IEEE 754 single precision floating-point number during simulation.  I'm using `$display()` and attempting to print the number in both ModelSim and in my console (using Icarus Verilog on a Mac).  My best attempt so far is this:

```
wire [31:0] out;
wire signed [200:0] conv = -1**(out[31]) * (1'b1 + (out[22:0] * 2'b10**($signed(8'b11101001)))) * 2'b10**(out[30:23] + $signed(8'b10000001));

$display("The number is %f", conv);
```

The width of converted is just arbitrarily large.  For 11000001100111010000100000110000, the above will print out -16.000000.  I've determined that the sign and the exponent parts work, but the mantissa, which is being multiplied by 2^-23, is just going to 0.  The real answer should be -19.628998.

Any ideas what I'm missing?  Is this even possible in Verilog?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is [$bitstoreal](https://www.hdlworks.com/hdl_corner/verilog_ref/items/SystemRealConversionFuncs.htm), something like;

```
wire [31:0] out;

$display("The number is %f", $bitstoreal(out));
```